# Prove a relation $\mathcal R$ is reflexive if and only if its complement $\overline{\mathcal R}$ is irreflexive (strict).

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, relations

Given a homogeneous binary relation $\mathcal R$ over a set $A$, $\mathcal{R}$ is reflexive if:

$$\forall a \in A:(a,a) \in \mathcal R$$
Prove a relation $\mathcal R$ is reflexive if and only if its complement $\overline{\mathcal R}$ is irreflexive (strict).

---

$\Longrightarrow$

By the definition of complement relation:

$$\forall a,b \in A :(a,b) \in \mathcal R \implies (a,b) \notin \overline{\mathcal R}$$

Taking $a=b$ follows:

$$\forall a \in A :(a,a) \in \mathcal R \implies (a,a) \notin \overline{\mathcal R}$$

Which is true since $\mathcal R$ is reflexive.

$\Longleftarrow$

By the definition of complement relation:

$$\forall a,b \in A :(a,b) \in \overline{\mathcal R} \implies (a,b) \notin \mathcal R$$

Taking $a=b$ follows:

$$\forall a \in A :(a,a) \in \overline{\mathcal R} \implies (a,a) \notin \mathcal R$$

Since $ \overline{\mathcal R}$ is irreflexive, hence $\forall a \in A :(a,a) \in \overline{\mathcal R}$ is never true, and hence its negation is always true for all $a \in A$, however I still cannot finish the proof.

Another way is using contradiction argument, assume $\overline{\mathcal R}$ is irreflexive, but $\mathcal R$ is not reflexive, i.g.:
$$\forall a \in A :(a,a) \notin \overline{\mathcal R}$$

And $$\exists a \in A :(a,a) \notin \mathcal R$$

From here we see that exists such $a \in A$ satisfying the two conditions $(a,a) \notin \overline{\mathcal R}$ and $(a,a) \notin \mathcal R$, but do we end up with a contradiction?

Can someone help me finishing this proof?

Comment: Using the contradiction argument in the second part of the proof, note that since $\mathcal{R}$ and $\overline{\mathcal R}$ are complement of each other, then $\mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R} = A \times A$. Given that $a \in A$, then $(a,a)$ is at least in one of the sets $\mathcal{R}$ or $\overline{\mathcal R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\implies$ part of the proof is fine.

Now for the $\Longleftarrow$ part:

Use proof by contraction. Suppose $\overline{\mathcal R}$ is irreflexive and $R$ is not reflexive. By definition of complement, we know that $\mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R} = A \times A$. Let $a \in A$, such that $(a,a) \notin \overline{\mathcal R}$ (since $\overline{\mathcal R}$ is irreflexive) and $(a,a) \notin \mathcal{R}$ (since $\mathcal{R}$ is not reflexive, then such ordered pair in this conditions must exists). From here we deduce that $(a,a) \notin A \times A$, which is a contradiction. $\square$

Comment: But if $A = \{ 1,2\}$, then $A \times A = \{ (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2) \}$

Comment: Let $A$ be a set. Then $A \times A = \{ (x,y) | x,y \in A\}$

Comment: Let $A$ be a set, and let $\mathcal{R}$ be a relation on $A$. To prove that $\mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R} = A \times A$, we have to show that $\mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R} \subseteq A \times A$ and $A \times A \subseteq \mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R}$.

Comment: Suppose that $(x,y) \in \mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R}$. Then $(x,y) \in \mathcal{R}$ or $(x,y) \in \overline{\mathcal R}$. In the first case, we have that $x \mathcal{R} y$. Since $\mathcal{R}$ is a relation on $A$, then $x, y \in A$. Hence $(x,y) \in A \times A$. In the second case, we have that $(x,y) \in \overline{\mathcal R}$. But $\overline{\mathcal R} = A \times A - R$. So $(x,y) \in A \times A$. In both cases, if $(x,y) \in \mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R}$, then $(x,y) \in A \times A$. Therefore $\mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R} \subseteq A \times A$.

Comment: Suppose that $(z,w) \in A \times A$. Hence: or $(z,w) \in \mathcal{R}$, or $(z,w) \notin \mathcal{R}$. In the 1st case, since $(z,w) \in \mathcal{R}$, then $(z,w) \in \mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R}$. In the 2nd case, we have that $(z,w) \in A \times A$ and $(z,w) \notin \mathcal{R}$. Then $(z,w) \in A \times A - \mathcal{R}$. So $(z,w) \in \overline{\mathcal R}$. Then $(z,w) \in \mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R}$. In both cases, $(z,w) \in A \times A$ implies $(z,w) \in \mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R}$. Then $A \times A \subseteq \mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R}$

Comment: Therefore we conclude that $A \times A = \mathcal{R} \cup \overline{\mathcal R}$

Answer (score 1):

Concise version:

Define: $$\Delta:=\{(a,a)\mid a\in A\}$$ which is the so-called *diagonal*.

Then $\mathcal R$ is reflexive iff $\Delta\subseteq\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal R$ is irreflexive iff $\Delta\cap\mathcal R=\varnothing$.

Observe that the last mentioned condition is equivalent with $\Delta\subseteq\mathcal R^{\complement}$, saying exactly that $\mathcal R^{\complement}$ is reflexive.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add an extra answer that highlights the underlying logic. Start with the definition of $\overline{\mathcal{R}}$.

$$
\forall a \forall b : (a,b)\in \mathcal{R} \Leftrightarrow (a,b) \not\in \overline{\mathcal{R}} \tag{1}
$$
Set $a=b$ to get:
$$
\forall a : (a,a)\in \mathcal{R} \Leftrightarrow (a,a) \not\in \overline{\mathcal{R}} \tag{2}
$$
In $(2)$ we can distribute the "for all" to get:$^*$
$$
(\forall a\space (a,a)\in\mathcal{R}) \Leftrightarrow (\forall a \space (a,a)\not\in\overline{\mathcal{R}}) \tag{3}
$$
Now $(3)$ says precisely that $\mathcal{R}$ is reflexive iff $\overline{\mathcal{R}}$ is irreflexive.

---

$^*$In general, if you have properties $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ of an object $x$, and you know that for any $x$, $P(x)$ holds iff $Q(x)$ holds (i.e., $\forall x(P(x)\leftrightarrow Q(x))$), then you know that $P(x)$ holds for all $x$ iff $Q(x)$ holds for all $x$ (i.e., $(\forall x\space P(x))\leftrightarrow (\forall x\space Q(x))$).